# What theme does @quellenform use

Tags: theme

@quellenform if you don't mind, could you tell me what theme you use to make everything white? I can't find it anywhere as all of Blender's white themes make my nodes blue. Is it a custom theme or available online? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't put too much hope in it if I were you, because it's not really practical to work with, but for the one or other screenshot for BSE it can be nice sometimes.

[image: quellenform - BSE.xml]

You can download the theme here: https://e.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=MWPotalK

Please note that the theme is not 100% finished, and therefore still has edges in some places.

*PS: Yes, it's a custom theme, color-coded specifically for this site.*

Comment: This time the answer is for a blatantly off-topicness question... This is getting more and more amusing :D

Comment: @ quellenform ill keep that in mind but Thank you so much :D

Comment: @dfggfd If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by pressing the checkbox on the top left.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Yes, that sometimes also results in a great learning effect. ...also for me ;-)

Comment: @YousufChaudhry yep I'm sorry I just couldn't write a comment because I don't have 50 reputation points :) ill delete this post if you think I should?

Comment: @dfggfd ...you did nothing wrong, everything is fine! (In my opinion)

Comment: @quellenform Of course, publicity :D

Comment: @dfggfd I also won't suggest deleting it, since after all it can have a relevant answer ;)